# Limit of two "entangled" sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $0<a<b<\infty$ and define the sequences $x_1 =a$, $y_1=b$ and >$x_{n+1}=2(x_n^{-1}+y_n^{-1})^{-1}$, $y_{n+1}=\sqrt{x_n y_n}$. Prove that the sequences converge >to the same limit.

It is easy to prove that both sequences form a contraction, i.e. $x_n\leq x_{n+1} \leq y_{n+1}\leq y_n$. Then both sequences will converge to the same limit if I can prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(y_n-x_n)=0$. I'm stucked at this last step, because

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
y_{n+1}-x_{n+1} &\leq y_n - \frac{2}{\frac{1}{x_n}+\frac{1}{y_n}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{y_n}{x_n}-1}{\frac{1}{x_n}+\frac{1}{y_n}}\\
&=(y_n-x_n)\frac{y_n}{x_n+y_n}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

This last term is giving me trouble because I cannot find a suitable upper bound that does not depend on $a$ or $b$. Of course this last term $<b/(2a)$, but then one has to play with $b/a\leq1$ or $b/a>1$.

[Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3385993/proving-two-recursive-sequences-converge)

Comment: Let $X_n:=1/x_n, Y_n:=1/y_n$. Then they define an [Arithmetic-Geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean) progression which converges to a common mean.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you already know that $(x_n)$ is increasing and upper-bounded by $y_1=b$ (the same for $(y_n)$ decreasing and also lower-bounded by $0$). So they converge.

Let $l$ and $l'$ be these limits.

Then $l' = \lim_{n\to\infty}y_{n+1} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{x_ny_n} = \sqrt{ll'}$ and the conclusion follows.

Comment: Ok, yes, but this is the link in"realated" that I included. My first attempt was to purse the "contraction" approach and I still want to see if it is possible to conclude the argument in this vein.